# How to focus each element of custom view in TVOS

Tags: swift, tvos

I am working on TVOS. In my UIviewcontroller class, I have taken custom view at left side for side menu and rest of the screen with collection view. side menu is having multiple images and labels. For UIcollectionView, Focus environment is working fine but for side menu, I am not able to focus on each element. How can I focus on Images and Labels of Side menu so that I can perform action while selecting them.

Comment: Just curious, is this new development or an existing development? IMHO I think SwiftUI does provide a lot for free if that is something you can develop in.

Comment: Also it might help to watch the apple developer videos (https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/) on tvos, learning the basics though time consuming would go a long way in helping you.

Comment: This is new development.

Comment: If you want to SwiftUI, in my personal opinion SwiftUI is a lot more enjoyable to develop in. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10042/